# Vue JS/Vuex - Getter ID not updating with route param ID

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm getting the ID of a user based on the ID I pass in my route params. When I first load the page and access one of the users, the getter displays the ID from the route param accordingly, however once I go back, and click on another user, the ID from the param does not match with the getter. Instead the getter shows the ID of the previously accessed user. Can anyone kindly suggest a solution for this?

```
setup() {
    const store = vuexStore;
    const adminId = router.currentRoute.params.adminId;
    console.log("ID param:", adminId);

    getSelectedAdmin();
    const selectedAdmin = computed(() => store.getters.getSelectedAdmin);
    console.log("getter Id:", selectedAdmin.value.id);

    function getSelectedAdmin() {
      return store.dispatch(GET_ADMIN_BY_ID, adminId)
    }

    return {
      selectedAdmin,
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the user in the **onMounted hook**.
(I use the script setup, *vue-router@next* & *vuex@next*)

```html
<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted, computed } from 'vue'
  import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
  import { useStore } from 'vuex'

  const store = useStore()
  const route = useRoute()

  const selectedAdmin = computed(() => store.getters['getSelectedAdmin'])
  onMounted(async () => { await store.dispatch('GET_ADMIN_BY_ID', route.params.adminId) })
</script>

<template>
 <div v-if="selectedAdmin">
  {{ selectedAdmin.username }}
 </div>
 <div v-else>Loading ...</div>
</template>
```

In your store :

- Set initial value for selectedAdmin to null
- In the GET_ADMIN_BY_ID action, reset selectedAdmin to null before updating

```js
const state = {
  currentAdmin: null,
}

const mutations = {
  SET_ADMIN: (state, payload) => state.currentAdmin = payload
}

const getters = {
  getSelectedAdmin: (state) => state.currentAdmin
}

const actions = {
  GET_ADMIN_BY_ID: ({ commit }, id) => {
    commit('SET_ADMIN', null)
    return axios.get(`admin/${id}`)
    .then((response) => { commit('SET_ADMIN', response.data) })
    .catch((err) => { commit('SET_ADMIN', null) })
  }
```